# The browser download application/x-httpd-php instead of show the index page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, browser, httpd.conf

I have recently uploaded a website very similar to the others hosted in the same server, but for this website when i try to access at the homepage with firefox the browser downloads the file `application/x-httpd-php` instead of show the index page. I have searched on this website for a solution, and i have done the following implementations:

I have added in `httpd.conf` the following lines:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

and then i have restarted the service httpd.

I have also added in `.htaccess` the following lines:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Despite this, the problem has not been fixed.

Comment: What is the filename of you site's index page?

Comment: @Koala Yeung the filename of the index page is index.php

Comment: Have to you read any online article about normal Apache + PHP setup? People usually use `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` and `AddType text/html .php`, are they?

Comment: @I have tried to add them but this has not solved the issue. I don't care about Apache + PHP setup, i am able to install them by myself but in the server there is Plesk and are intalled by default. All the websites hosted are working but well but on ALL the new websites that i add have the same problem, the pages (included index.hml) are downloaded instead of executed.

Comment: You have to remove your AddType rules that you mentioned here with ".htm" and ".html" here. They are non-sense.

Comment: @KoalaYeung,what's difference between `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` and `AddType text/html .php`?